# Why are all system environment variables null in apache HTTPD?

Tags: apache

I cannot use any *system* environment variables in `SetHeader`:

```
RequestHeader set "X-Header1" "%{USERNAME}e"
RequestHeader set "X-Header2" "%{TMP}e"
RequestHeader set "X-Header3" "%{ENV:TMP}"
SetEnv HELLO "world"
RequestHeader set "X-Header4" "%{HELLO}e"
```

Results in the following response:

```
X-Header1: (null)
X-Header2: (null)
X-Header3: (null)
X-Header4: world
```

So Apache only picks up it's "own" environment variables but not those from the system environment which started the httpd process.

I *know* these environment variables (e.g. `TMP`) are set.

Apache 2.4 Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_env.html), You need to pass environmental variables from the shell using **PassEnv** Directive first before you can use them. Here's an example:

```
PassEnv USERNAME TMP
```